# How to insert saved Leaflet widget into Rmarkdown HTML output

Tags: r, r-markdown, htmlwidgets, r-leaflet

I create a Leaflet widget and save it locally:

```r
library(htmlwidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)

shp = st_read("/path/to/some/shapefile.shp")

m = shp %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  setView(lng = -70, lat = 40, zoom = 11)

saveWidget(m, "m.html")
```

Now I want to load this widget in a Rmarkdown chunk:

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "author"
date: "5/8/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

etc etc etc

```{r}
function_that_loads_widget("m.html")
```

etc etc etc
````

I've tried `htmltools::includeHTML()` but that makes the entire HTML output one big widget. The text of the report is not displayed.

I realize I could put the the code that created the Leaflet widget directly in the Rmarkdown chunk, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: `saveWidget` doesn't really do what its name suggests.  It's really more like `renderWidget`.  I don't think you can recover the widget from that.  If you want to save an R object, use `saveRDS()` or `save()`, and read the object back with `readRDS()` or `load()`.

Comment: Why not `source` the code creating the widget directly?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer  (not OP):  My use case is that I have a R script running daily to update PNG and maps and uploads them to S3.  I also have a blog built using blogdown that refers to  these PNG so that I don't have to rebuild the blog every day.

sourcing the code would mean having to rebuild the blog and pushing to github for hosting  every day.

Answer (score 2):

knitr::include_url() appears to be the solution.  This works for my blogdown post.

````
```{r, out.width="100%"}
knitr::include_url("url_of_html", height="1080px")
```
````